# Is it possible to make a table with only horizontal borders in reportlab?

Tags: python, reportlab

Good day,

I have an array/list of the following design: `data = [['colour', 'apple', 'pear', 'peach'], ['RED', 1, 2, 5], ['YELLOW', 6, 7, 9]]`. I have seen many tutorials explaining how to add the inner grid and the box. But I would like to have somewhat close to such:

[image]

Do you know how to add only horizontal borders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out LineAbove and LineBelow in [TableStyle page 77](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)

```
LIST_STYLE = TableStyle([('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,0), 2, colors.green),
    ('LINEABOVE', (0,1), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('LINEBELOW', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 2, colors.green)])
```

Comment: and how to assign these only for the header and footer of the table?

Comment: I can't see your image through the firewall where I am. You determine which lines you want and select those - if you're not sure how many from the top or bottom in advance, but you can determine that and assign a variable for it, you can use those in the TableStyle....

Comment: sorry, worked it out. Panicked a bit, forgot `,` and code was failing, decided that I was doing everything wrong^^ Now it works. And if I want to outline both lines above and below, I need somewhat like:
`tableStyle = TableStyle([
                             ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,0), 0.25, colors.darkgray),
                             ('LINEBELOW', (0,0), (-1,0), 0.25, colors.darkgray),
                             ('LINEABOVE', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.darkgray),
                             ('LINEBELOW', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.darkgray)
                       ])`